# Replacement coins for At The Gates of Loyang

Tags: custom-game-pieces, at-the-gates-of-loyang

I have the game, and one of the first things I noticed was the cardboard money. Not a fan, even though in this game it's really just another resource, and doesn't change hands often.

Anyone have a source for good replacements? I'm looking for metal Cash-style coins in two sizes, and preferably different colors. A quick search for "Chinese Luck Coins" brings up good results for one size, but I can't find a good second size (larger *or* smaller, or in a significantly different metal color) to replicate the "1" and "5" coins.

Comment: They don't have different sizes (which is why I'm putting this in a comment not an answer), but Mused Fable has Realm Coins & Pirate Coins. They're all about the size of a US quarter, and come in gold, silver and copper colors. I have a set of Realm coins and they're really nice. Http://musedfable.com

Comment: They do look good, but not in the Chinese style.

Comment: Oops, yeah. I missed that part. They've said that they want to do different styles of coins. Maybe they'll eventually do Chinese-style ones.

Comment: Caravans of Asia has wooden Chinese-style coins.  (I'm the game designer, btw.)  http://boardgamegeek.com/image/1439357/caravans-of-asia

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine got some Mexico pesos.  They seem to work fairly good, and are fairly heavy.  Different sizes as well.  How you get them if you don't have a friend traveling there, I'm not sure.  But I wouldn't be surprised if they aren't a cheap option for metal money.

http://coins.about.com/od/worldcoins/ig/World-Coins-Gallery-Index/Mexico-Money---Coins.htm